# SQL query 1 col & 1000 rows to pandas dataframe 10 cols&100 rows

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I need your help in this tricky problem. I have an SQL query result with one column and 1000 rows. This SQL query is actually a self join query on a table and the 1000 are actually 10 sets of the same 100 id`s. So the question is: How can I change the dimensions of this SQL query result in order to process it with pandas dataFrame? I know that pandas dataframes are always 2d and I can`t use pandas.pivot because I do not have unique indexes.

EDIT1:

An example of what I want to do.

*SQL query result*

1 column and rows N1 to N1000

*Necessary dataframe*

Columns: Column1  /  Column2  /  Column3   /   Column4     /    (and so on)

Rows:   N1 to N100 / N101 to N200 / N201 to N300 /  N301 to N400  /    (and so on)

EDIT2:
A small example with values.The SQL query is based on a self join on a table of 5 people and their ages. The values in the query are the age differences between two persons each time.

*SQL query*

**Age difference**

N1(=Age difference between Person 1 and Person 1)

N2(=Age difference between Person 1 and Person 2)

N3(=Age difference between Person 1 and Person 3)

N4(=Age difference between Person 1 and Person 4)

N5(=Age difference between Person 1 and Person 5)

N6(=Age difference between Person 2 and Person 1)

N7(=Age difference between Person 2 and Person 2)

N8(=Age difference between Person 2 and Person 3)

N9(=Age difference between Person 2 and Person 4)

N10(=Age difference between Person 2 and Person 5)

...

N25(=Age difference between Person 5 and Person 5)

*Necessary dataframe*

**Person1**----**Person2**-----**Person3**-----**Person4**-----**Person5**

N1-------------N6-------------N11-------------N16-------------N21

N2-------------N7-------------N12-------------N17-------------N22

N3-------------N8-------------N13-------------N18-------------N23

N4-------------N9-------------N14-------------N19-------------N24

N5-------------N10------------N15-------------N20-------------N25

Comment: Is your "SQL query result" a python object? What type?

Comment: No. I wanted to know all the ways to reshape my result before I use for example pandas or numpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to understand your task, but here's simple example, it gives you an idea to start with:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
>>> conn.execute('create table test (id int, value int)')
>>> conn.execute('insert into test select 1, 1 union all select 2, 2')
>>> df = pd.read_sql('select t1.id, t2.id, t1.value * t2.value from test as t1 cross join test as t2', conn)
>>> df
   id1  id2  value
0    1    1      1
1    1    2      2
2    2    1      2
3    2    2      4
>>> df.columns = ['id1','id2','value']
>>> df.pivot(index='id1', columns='id2')
    value   
id2     1  2
id1         
1       1  2
2       2  4
```

**edit**

```
>>> conn.execute('insert into ages select 6 union all select 24 union all select 14 union all select 16 union all select 65')
>>> df = pd.read_sql('select t1.age - t2.age from ages as t1 cross join ages as t2', conn)
>>> df.column = ['diff']
>>> a = pd.DataFrame.from_records(product(range(5), range(5)), columns=['a','b'])
>>> res = pd.concat([df, a],axis=1)
>>> res.pivot(index='a', columns='b', values='diff')
b   0   1   2   3   4
a                    
0   0 -18  -8 -10 -59
1  18   0  10   8 -41
2   8 -10   0  -2 -51
3  10  -8   2   0 -49
4  59  41  51  49   0
```

Comment: I see what you have done but your result is a little different in logic than what I want. I edited my question with an example of what I need. I tried to use pivot as you have suggested and I get error message either ValueError: cannot label index with a null key (although it is not null) or ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape.

Comment: why do you need to do this? Just fetch one set of ids from the database and then duplicate it

Comment: Because values N1 to N1000 are all different to each other.

Comment: which values? You said you have 1 column (id) and those id's are repeated. I'd consider creating simple example of your input, smaller in size and desired output

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Mr. Roman Pekar thank you very much.